# Elegant way to import repetitive data to ms-excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Problem is:
Text file containing repetitive paten of data:

```
Object:1  
value1:abc  
value2:234  
value3:xyz  
value4:date  

Object:2  
value1:def  
value2:567   
value3:asd  
value4:date  

Object:3  
.  
.
```

And so.
I would like to import it to excel as a table looking something like this:

```
Object  value1 Value2 Value3 Value4  
  1         abc      234   xyz    date  
  2         def      567   asd    date  
.  
.
```

I found dirty solution by using offset function, but I've got a feeling there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more robust option, I'm not sure it's more elegant.

1. split your data into columns (data - text to columns)
2. add two calculated columns:

   - object#: `=IF(A2="Object",B2,C1)`
   - ID: `=A2&"_"&C2`
3. create skeleton of your destination table with row and column headers
4. enter formula and fill down and across
   `=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(G$1&"_"&$F2,$D:$D,0))`

Key here is to correctly use absolute / relative references
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Máté Juhász's answer is very robust.  If your data has irregularities, like some missing elements, his solution will still get values into the right place.  If your data isn't pristine, using his solution would be a good idea.

If you know that your data is clean (nothing missing, everything reliably follows the pattern), you can get away with a simpler approach that uses the data as-is, it doesn't require splitting the data or helper columns.  This approach relies on direct references to data cell locations, so the data needs to follow the pattern and be where it's supposed to be.

[image]

It's based on two formulas combined into one.  The first extracts the value from any record:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

This looks for the colon and takes everything to the right of it.

The second formula relates a location in your results matrix to a source data cell:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1)
```

INDIRECT builds a cell reference.  The formula works with groups of six rows.  The first cell in the results matrix (C2) points to the first data cell (A1).  Each column to the right moves down a row in the data.  Each row in the results matrix moves to the next group of six rows.

To adjust this for the actual locations of your data and results matrix:

- Replace `$C$2:C2` with the starting location of your results matrix, observing the $s for absolute addressing.
- Replace "A" with the column your source data is in.
- The `+1` at the end of `ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1` is the row number of the first row of data.  My example starts in row 1.

The actual formula substitutes the second formula, which gives the data cell location, for the `A1` in the first formula.  A1 appears three times, so the formula gets a little long:

```
=MID(INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1),FIND(":",INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1))+1,LEN(INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1)))
```

You can shorten the formula by replacing the last of the three references to A1.  The last one, LEN(A1) is just to provide the MID function with how many characters to retrieve.  Using LEN(A1) ensures that it will be enough characters.  You can replace that with an arbitrary number that's larger than any value you will see (MID just runs out of characters to retrieve).  So for example, if you use `99`, the first formula would be:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,99)
```

And the combined formula would be:

```
=MID(INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1),FIND(":",INDIRECT("A"&(ROWS($C$2:C2)-1)*6+1+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1))+1,99)
```

Paste and adjust the formula in the first cell of your results matrix, then copy or drag it across and down as needed.

I suspect your OFFSET formula was similar to the INDIRECT function here, anchored to the first data cell, and offsetting from there based on row and column of the results matrix.